# How to shallow copy and deep copy a jagged array using ToArray()?

Tags: c#, arrays, copy, jagged-arrays

```
int[] nm = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(),int.Parse);
int[][]graph = new int[nm[0]][];
int[][] meltedGraph = new int[nm[0]][];
for (int i = 0; i < nm[0]; i++)
{
    graph[i] = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(), int.Parse);
    // deep copy
    meltedGraph[i] = graph[i].ToArray();

}
// shallow copy
//meltedGraph = graph.ToArray();

    input
    
    5 7
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 2 4 5 3 0 0
    0 3 0 2 5 2 0
    0 7 6 2 4 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    
    3 3
    0 0 0
    0 0 0
    0 0 0
```

...

I am solving an algorithm problem, and I need to put the input values ​​into "graph" and "meltedGraph" like the code above.
In that way, when accessing and inserting each row of a variable array through a loop statement, it becomes a deep copy.
However, if you use ToArray() on the array itself without directly accessing the row, Shallow Copy occurs, and I wonder why.

Comment: Why do you think a deep copy *should* happen? Where in the docs of `ToArray` does it say that it will perform a deep copy (especially given it has no idea what a deep copy means in your context)?

Comment: The meaning of shallow copy was that if the value of any element in the graph is changed, the changed element value is also reflected in the melted graph. Conversely, deep copy means that the element values ​​of the meltedgraph do not change even if the elements of the graph change. When I read the docs of ToArray, it seems that a shallow copy should occur using the copy function internally, but I'm not sure why deep copy occurs when accessing rows of a mutable array.

Comment: `meltedGraph[i] = graph[i].ToArray();` means they are two different arrays. If you do `meltedGraph[i] = graph[i];` then you get a shallow copy of the outer array